# Unified interface for pure and constrained monadic functions

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, overloading, typeclass

I want to create overloaded function by `x` type variable which can unify these two types:

```
append :: A -> x -> A
append :: MonadThrow m => A -> x -> m A
```

What type class should I write in that case? Currently I have something like this:

```
class MyClasss (x :: *) (m :: * -> *) | x -> m where
    type MonadConstraint x :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
    append :: MonadConstraint x m => A -> x -> m A
```

> I can emulate pure version using `Identity` monad and creating helper function.

But when I create instance like this one:

```
instance MyClass X m where ...
```

I see the following compilation error:

```
    • Illegal instance declaration for 'MyClass Text m'
        The coverage condition fails in class 'MyClass'
          for functional dependency: 'p -> m'
        Reason: lhs type 'X' does not determine rhs type 'm'
        Un-determined variable: m
    • In the instance declaration for 'MyClass X m'
   |
94 | instance MyClass X m where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What can I do to abstract these two functions?

Comment: When I paste in your class, I get `error: Not in scope: type variable ‘p’`.

Comment: @Alec sorry, I had type in my question. Fixed!

Comment: So you want `p -> m` to be `x -> m` too, right?

Comment: @Alec Yes, you're right. Sorry, I just changed my real-life example to make it a little bit simpler and accidentally forgot to change all places...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I recommend this, but it compiles and works, at least for the given cases.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses,
             AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import Control.Monad.IO.Class

data A = A Int deriving Show
data X1 = X1
data X2 = X2
```

We make the return type to be expressed by a type function.

```
class MyClass (x :: *) (m :: * -> *) where
  type Ret x m :: *
  append :: A -> x -> Ret x m
```

If `X1` does not lead to a monadic result, we make `Ret X1 m` non-monadic.

```
instance MyClass X1 m where
  type Ret X1 m = A
  -- append :: A -> X1 -> A
  append a x = a
```

Otherwise, we make `Ret X1 m` monadic.

```
instance MonadIO m => MyClass X2 m where
  type Ret X2 m = m A
  -- append :: MonadIO m => A -> X2 -> m A
  append a x = liftIO (putStrLn "hi!") >> return a
```

The downside is that this involves ambiguous types, so we have to turn on that extension. However, the following tests pass just fine since GHC is able to resolve the ambiguities.

```
test1 :: A
test1 = append (A 3) X1
```

Above, nothing tells GHC what `m` is, but since there is only one instance for `X1`, no error arises.

```
test2 :: IO A
test2 = append (A 3) X2
```

Ditto for `X2`.

Comment: So it should also work if I have two instances `instance MonadIO m => MyClass X2 m` and `instance MonadIO m => MyClass X3 m where`? Because there's only single instance per `x` type?